# Diff between pyinstaller version 4.2 and pyinstaller version 6.4.0

Tags: python, pyinstaller

I have created pyinstaller executable with 4.2 (which is from python3.5) and 6.4.0 (from python3.8) versions.

from pyinstaller 4.2 version (which is from python3.5), i have created exe file. But when i check the content of this exe using readelf tool, i could see type is DYN (Shared object file).

from pyinstaller 6.4.0 version (which is from python3.8), i have created exe file. But when i check the content of this exe using readelf tool, i could see type is EXEC (Executable file).

So want to know differences between these two.

Also i am seeing size diff, is it bcz of exec itself has all details as library files ?

Could anyone please help on this ?

Thank You.

is it changed from shared library to standalone exe now ?

Comment: https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/issues/5344 - this is about ubuntu specifically, but I would assume that it also applies to windows. In short: Both are executables (as you would expect)

Comment: @FlyingTeller Thank you for information. Also need one more information with python3.5 size of an exe is 5.4MB and with python3.8 it is 9.4MB, why there is difference in size ?